# Powershell Set-Variable resets Variable instead of updating it

Tags: powershell

I'm confused on how to use `Set-Variable` to change a specific value in a variable. I don't understand the resulting behavior. I am trying this in Powershell 5.1.

If I create a new variable with `New-Variable`

```
New-Variable -Name TestVariable -Value @{Name1 = 'Value1'; Name2 = 'Value2'}
```

And then I try to change it with `Set-Variable`

```
Set-Variable -Name TestVariable -Value @{Name1 = 'NewValue'}
```

Why is my output now:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name1                          NewValue
```

and not as expected:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name1                          NewValue
Name2                          Value2
```

`Set-Variable` appears to reset the whole variable instead of changing it. Or creating a new variable without the `-Force` setting, which is kind of scary.

The description from the Microsoft docs say:

> The Set-Variable cmdlet assigns a value to a specified variable or
> changes the current value. If the variable does not exist, the cmdlet
> creates it.

Do I misunderstand the **or changes** part somehow?

I've also tried to store the parameters in a variable itself instead of writing it out after the `-Value` however that results in the same behavior as expected.

Now if I do change the value without `Set-Variable` it works just fine.

```
$TestNewVariable.Name1 = 'NewValue'
```

and the output is exactly as expected:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name1                          NewValue
Name2                          Value2
```

The Solution would be instead of changing a value in the variable is to just write all values again. However I'd be very interested to know why the `Set-Variable` is not just changing the value or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is correct -- you're setting the value of `$TestVariable` to a brand new hashtable (what you see as a compound value is really just one thing, try `$TestVariable.GetType()`). `Set-Variable` can't be used to change *parts* of a variable because it really doesn't care about the variable's type -- you could equally successfully change a `0` value to the new hashtable. The solution, if you can call it that, is to simply not use `Set-Variable` for this. You can use `$TestVariable = @{}` to initialize the thing to empty and then fill it as you please.

Comment: This somewhat defeats the entire purpose of having `Get-Variable`. `Set-Variable` seems to do the same thing with minor advantages. It does still seem like a flaw to not be able to change an actual value even if `Set-Variable` does not care what is is actually storing.

Comment: Both `Get-Variable` and `Set-Variable` are largely superfluous unless used with the options that can't be folded into regular variable access, yes. The vast majority of scripts have no use for them. Doing type-appropriate access is not something `Set-Variable` is designed for, though, nor do you even need it for that. Assuming you don't know the variable name in advance but do know it's supposed to be a hash, `(Get-Variable "TestVariable").Value.Name1 = "NewValue"` works just as well. The "real" problem (if you can call it that) is that `Hashtable` is a reference type, not a value type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as the name `Set-Variable` might suggest that it's for editing variable Values it is solely to edit Variable Properties such as -Scope, -Visibility, -Description etc. Among them can be the -Value of a Variable but only the Value as a whole and not Value Properties since `Set-Variable` does not care about the Value Properties at any point and therefore cannot edit them.